# Recatjs -Webpack build failing at Html code className="somehting"

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use webpack for optimising my reactjs project by using webpack and codesplit but some thing i am missing below is my webpack.config.js.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 entry: {
main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
},     module: {
 rules: [
  // JavaScript
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  },

  // Images
  {
    test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
  // Fonts and SVGs
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
    type: 'asset/inline',
  },
  // CSS, PostCSS, and Sass
  {
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader',
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localsConvention: 'camelCase',
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
       },
      ],
   },
 ],
},
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
filename: '[name].bundle.js',
},
plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'public/index.html',
}),
],
};
```

```html
ERROR in ./src/components/provider/PersonalDetails2/index.jsx 32:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

 return (
>     <div className="root">
|       <Grid container spacing={0} className="divMain">
|         <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} style={{ minHeight: "990px" }} className="divLeftGrid">
```

Please can any one guide me to setup webpack with code splitting, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install "sass-resources-loader" and add it like below in your webpack.config :D

```
       {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
       },
       {
        loader: "sass-resources-loader",
       },
```

Comment: no luck, tried installing 'sass-resources-loader'